# Have the MacBooks Pro in 2011 and 2012 still shipped with installation disks?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I'm looking into acquiring some older Apple hardware and am wondering how long Apple still shipped hardware with installation disks. So when did Apple stop shipping installation disks (or more specifically: did the 2011 and 2012 MacBookPros still ship *with* disks)?

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X 10.7 Lion was released to manufacturing on July 1, 2011 and was the first Mac OS that was not made available on optical media. I believe that the last MBP to ship with optical media were the Early 2011 models which were introduced in February 2011 shipping with Mac OS X 10.6.6 meaning that the Late 2011 MBP introduced October 2011 and shipping with Mac OS X 10.7.2 would have been the first to ship without optical media.

Comment: gotcha, okay thanks, I'm getting a new-but-used late-2011 MBP next week from the original owner and he said he couldn't find any discs and wasn't sure if they came with them and I didn't know either since I have only early-2011 MBP's.

Comment: In some cases you could talk Apple Support into providing media. I did that and ended up with a USB key with the OS on it around that time. Apple assumes that everyone has nice fast internet now and doesn't need media. Sigh...

Comment: I just got the Thunderbolt-to-Thunderbolt cables and just for extra measure mini-DP-to-mini-DP cables and still can't get the 2 MBP's and/or MBA to recognize each other screen-wise nor drive-wise, what am I doing wrong?